# disable ssl warnings in browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have self-sigmed SSL cert Is it possible to disable SSL warnings in Firefox 3+ or Google Crome ? I mean disable completely for all certificates&hosts or just for one root cert for all subdomains ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install your CA cert as a trusted provider into the browser you will not get warnings. If this is for other peoples browsers you don't have access to you are out of luck.

[How to add A cert to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities](http://wiki.wmtransfer.com/wiki/show/Installing+root+certificate+in+Google+Chrome).

Comment: I need more detailed explanation I have self-signed SSL cert When I access https://localhost I'mgetting warning about untrusted connection How can I avoid this warning ? I know I can add exeption - this  isn't a solution for my problem because I have lots of subdomains like http://www.anything.localhost

Comment: I never said add an exception I said add your CA to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities. I'll update my answer with a link that should help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an article how to generate SSL cert for subdomains
http://www.justinsamuel.com/2006/03/11/howto-create-a-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificate/

In Mozilla Firefox

http://wiki.wmtransfer.com/wiki/show/Installing+root+certificate+in+Mozilla+Firefox?q=Installing+root+certificate+in+

on my local PC I'm able to access any subdomains after I added this cert and made it trusted